# Python list variable substitution within multiline string...almost(edited)

Tags: python, format

(Edited, previous WAAAY below) - 
I got it to work by moving the string subst within the for loop, but the result automatically puts 5 tabs to the left that I can't seem to get rid of

I wanted to leave it up for a little bit to see if anyone has an answer and maybe to help someone that follows me...

Code:

```
for i in dns_list:
    with open("output.txt", "a") as output:
        alert_dns = textwrap.dedent("""
                    { 
                       \"tests\":[  
                           {{  
                             \"token\":\"DNS\",
                             \"type\":\"text\",
                             \"operator\":\"contains\",
                             \"preservecase\":false,
                             \"value\":\"%s\"
                          }
                       ]
                    """)%(i)
        alert_dns=alert_dns.strip()
        output.write(alert_dns.strip())
```

(Previous)
I have a list of domain names, I need to iterate through the list(dns_list) and place the variable 'insert' into a multiline string(alert_dns)-

```
alert_dns="""
{{  
 \"tests\":[  
     {{  
       \"token\":\"DNS\",
       \"type\":\"text\",
       \"operator\":\"contains\",
       \"preservecase\":false,
       \"value\":\"{insert}\"
    }}
 ]
}}
"""

dns_list=[]
temp_file_name = 'daily.csv'
with open(temp_file_name, 'r') as temp_file:
    lines = temp_file.read()
    dns = re.findall(urlmarker.WEB_URL_REGEX,lines)
    for i in dns:
        dns_list.append(i)

with open("output.txt", "w") as output:
    for i in dns_list:
        for insert in alert_dns:
            # i=insert
            alert_dns.format(i)
            output.write(alert_dns+'\n')
```

I keep getting -- 
    alert_dns.format(i)
KeyError: 'insert'

Comment: where do you need to insert the string? so you need to replace the "insert"

Comment: Yes, I thought I could use the format function to replace the insert with the contents of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `alert_dns.format(i)`

you should

```
alert_dns.format(insert=i)
```

Comment: Thanks @anthony-kong,  that puts 'insert' in the variable position in the multi line string "value":"{insert}" but not the value from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Alright this is the answer if anyone looks for it...

```
with open("output.txt", "w") as output:
    for i in dns_list:
        alert_dns = textwrap.dedent("""\
                    { 
                       \"tests\":[  
                           {{  
                             \"token\":\"DNS\",
                             \"type\":\"text\",
                             \"operator\":\"contains\",
                             \"preservecase\":false,
                             \"value\":\"%s\"
                          }
                       ]
                    """)%(i)
        output.write(alert_dns+'\n')
```